# How can I create std::function with array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to do array of functions with integers.

I ended up using this code: `std::function<void()> func[100];`

But when I'm trying to write into the array like this:

```
func[option] = draw("optionName", 255);
```

I get this error:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion
```

Edit:

Now I'm using this code to write function to the array:

```
func[option] = std::bind(draw, "optionName", 255);
```

But now it's giving me these errors:

```
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found (compiling source file source.cpp) Project C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  1491    
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)' (compiling source file source.cpp) Project C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  1491
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to call the function and assign the result to the array.

If you want to assign the function call with specific parameters, [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will help you do that.

> The function template `bind` generates a forwarding call wrapper for f. Calling this wrapper is equivalent to invoking f with some of its arguments bound to args.

Comment: No, I dont want to call the functions with specific parameters, I just want to write function `GRAPHICS::DRAW_SPRITE("CommonMenu", "shop_box_tickb", menuoptiontag + 0.00825f, (optionCount * 0.035f + 0.125f), 0.033, 0.043, 0.0, 255, 255, 255, 255);` into the array. Then I will call it like `drawMenuRight[2]();`.

Comment: @JosefMiegl like he says, use `std::bind`, it doesn't call the function, but binds the arguments, so that you can call it without specifying them

Comment: @Rakete1111 I don't know what exactly you mean, can you give me an example please?

Comment: @JosefMiegl sure, you have a function, `void foo(int, int)`, and you want to call it without arguments (pass them beforehand), you should use `std::bind`, like so `std::bind(foo, 1, 2);`. This will make a new unnamed function with no arguments, that you can assign to an array if you want to

Comment: @Rakete1111 ok, thanks. But it will giving me some weird errors. Please take a look at updated main thread

Comment: @JosefMiegl I think that should be another question, are you sure that those are the right number of arguments?

Comment: @JosefMiegl Sorry, but those are not the right arguments (or the right type)

Comment: @Rakete1111 what are the valid arguments then?

Comment: @Rakete1111 yea, the arguments are right. Or why its not valid?

Comment: @JosefMiegl As far as I know that specific error only happens when you use invalid parameters. I just have no idea